# Created VHD on USB drive, in use by SYSTEM, and can't attach/dismount in Disk Management

Tags: windows-server-2008, vhd

Currently using Server 2008 R2, and I attempted to create and attach a 1.5 TB VHD on a USB 2.0 drive.

I see the VHD file in the drive, but cannot attach it in Disk Management. I keep receiving an error message: `The file or directory is corrupted and unreadable.`

As this is a new VHD, I tried to delete the file, but receive yet another error: `The action can't be completed because the file is open in System.`

How do I attach or delete this drive?

Comment: How was it created if you can't use it?  Was it on the same machine?  What are the partition sizes and formats?

Comment: Created in Disk Management on the same machine that it's connected to. Not sure about partition size/format; I didn't get that far. The new VHD didn't even attach in Disk Management, so I couldn't actually initialize it.